# Leading zeros with decimal, Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a keypad of which inputs numbers for entering a payment.

With this i have leading zeros and would like to know the best way forward to dealing with/removing them efficiently.

[JSfiddle of the keypad](http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/k8Cbg/)

**The JS/JQ**

```
$(".button_epos_e").click( function() {

    btn_id = $(this).attr("id");                          
    btn_num = btn_id.replace("pay_", "");
    // alert(btn_num);

    decimal = $("#number").text();
    // alert(decimal);
    var truenumber = decimal.replace(".", "");
    // alert(truenumber);

    truenumber += btn_num;
     //alert(truenumber);

    postDecimal = truenumber.slice(-2);
    // alert(postDecimal);
    preDecimal = truenumber.replace(postDecimal, "");
    preDecInt = parseInt(preDecimal);
    // alert(preDecimal);
    newDecimal = preDecimal+"."+postDecimal;

    $("#number").html(newDecimal);  


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a bit of things that should be changed. But this should suffice for your needs:

```
preDecimal = +truenumber.slice(0, -2) + "";
```

The `+truenumber.slice(0, -2)` part converts the string to a number, deleting unnecessary leading zeros, and adding an empty string converts it back to a string (which isn't really necessary, though).

Comment: I tried a few routes, none of which worked, but this is perfect. I am reading more into slice now, many thanks.